# I need to implement captcha while registering a customer, how?

Tags: magento-1.9, captcha

Is there any free extension or plugin for implementing captcha while registering a customer ? or I need to configure custom level?

Comment: Hello YKB. Please check my answer and let me know if any query.

Answer (score 0):

Magento provide it's own captha  please use it.
Please Login in magento Admin.

1. Go To Symtem->Configuration->Customer->Customer Configuration->CAPTHA

[image]